# Developing Applications with Metro UI for Windows XP/7

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How do I go on developing applications with the Metro UI so that they work on Windows XP/Vista/7 ?

An example for an application is [MetroBackUp](http://metrobackup.codeplex.com/).

I'm on Windows 7 and have both Visual Studio 2010 and 11 Beta installed.

Is it compulsory to develop them in Windows 8 CP ?
Will they work in other OS ?

Comment: Note - Metro UI is just a style. The WinRT-based apps in Windows 8 are currently called "Metro Style Apps".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metro apps cannot be developed on OS Windows 7 or less. Metro Apps require [WinRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime) which is in Windows 8 onwards

> > **Important:**  Metro style app development is supported only on Windows 8 Consumer Preview. You can't develop Metro style apps on Windows 7 or Windows Server 8 Beta.

From the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx)

[Can I develop and debug Metro applications in Win7 with the Visual Studio 11 developer preview?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/toolsforwinapps/thread/0155ffb8-b526-46f3-9286-3befd5563b32)

**EDIT**

"Metro Style Apps" -> running on Windows Runtime, using Windows 8 UI features (like immersive UI, AppBar, Charm etc).

Metro style apps -> Normal .net apps, having look and feel similar to metro apps. (Example -> MetroBackup

Issue-> Will metro style apps run on Win XP?

They will as long as they do not use any Windows 7 feature (like TaskDialog, JumpList, etc)

Comment: Yeah I know about that but I'm getting confused between Metro Apps (which AFAIK only run on Win 8) and Metro-style apps (which run on Win 7). Now the question is whether they will work in XP ? The one I linked is working.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to develop metro style apps on Windows 7 then you can use the following libraries:

- [MetroToolkit](http://metrotoolkit.codeplex.com/)
- [MahApps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro)

Comment: good resource to know. Any more real applications as examples of Metro style?

Comment: I recall that I saw some, but unfortunately I cannot recall where I saw them.. sorry!

Comment: I can confirm that MahApps.Metro works on Windows XP using .NET Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop a Metro Style App, or an app running on top of the Windows Runtime (WinRT) - the app won't be able to run on versions of Windows older than Windows 8. You can share a lot of the code and possibly large chunks of the UI with a version of your app for older versions of Windows, depending on the stack you choose (DirectX/XAML/C++/C#/VB/HTML5+JS) and how you structure your code.

Another option is to develop an app that is not a "Metro Style App", but is simply styled to follow the Metro design language guidelines. There are libraries for WPF and possibly other frameworks that have styles that mimic the style of the Zune Software etc. The downside is - you will not be able to sell your application in the Windows Store.

If you are planning on using the XAML stack - the MVVM pattern allows to reuse a lot of the code between different platforms (WPF, Silverlight, Windows Phone, WinRT-XAML). MVVM is also possible in the HTML5/JS/WinJS stack with libraries like Knockout JS, so you might be able to develop your app in a way that works on any platform - even non-Windows one, albeit with the need to replace the use of the Windows 8 UI features (edge UI, app bar, charms bar) with alternative solutions.